# R - if values match in column A, how often do their corresponding values in column B match?

Tags: r

I am a novice R user and have a 3 million row dataset. I am using R 3.0.1. I have a data frame in R that looks as follows:

```
A1         B1

1          50       
1          50
1          45 
2          20
2          20
3          15
4          30
4          30
```

I'd like to know, if there are multiple of the same value in A1, what % of the time do the corresponding values match in column B1?

In the example above, there are 7 rows that are a duplicate in A1 and their corresponding values match 6/7 times. How can I get this result for millions of rows?

Note: For a group of given values in A1, there will not be more than 2 unique values in column B.

Comment: Will try soon - trying the below approach and the command is taking very long to run with such a large dataset.

Comment: Using the answer below from David that returns .5 which is what I would expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `data.table` approach (assuming `df` is your data set)

```
library(data.table)
df2 <- as.data.table(df)[, list(Match = if(.N > 1) sum(B1[1] == B1),
                                Dups = if(.N > 1) .N), by = A1]
```

This will create a data set that will show you the duplicates and matched frequencies per `A1`

```
df2
##    A1 Match Dups
## 1:  1     2    3
## 2:  2     2    2
## 3:  4     2    2
```

In order to reach your desired output, simply do

```
df2[, sum(Match)/sum(Dups)]
## [1] 0.8571429
```

Comment: @beginneR, I'm also not sure what he means by "what % of the time do the corresponding values match in column B1". Matched to what? To first instance? Don't know. How did you interpret it?

Comment: I have the data sorted by column A1. I'm trying to determine if there are multiple values in A1 that match, how often do the values in B1 match? So for all the 1's in A1 - how many times do their values in B1 match?

Comment: @beginneR that is a correct interpretation. The order of B1 rows does not matter.

Comment: And what happens for `c(5,5,2,2,3,3,3)` for example?

Comment: @beginneR, I'm talking to the OP. I mean if for a certain value of `A1` column there were several types of duplicated values in `B1` (like in my comment above), how would they be counted?

Comment: @beginneR - that's a very good question...if there are 6 of the same value in A1 and 3 pairs of 2 in column B1 then it should return it matches 2/3 of the time.

Comment: @DavidArenburg - this approach works when I use the small sample size data set I posted. When I try to apply this to my large data set the command does not seem to execute and keeps clocking. Any thoughts?

Comment: @DavidArenburg - I edited the post to reflect that. I'm trying to delete any rows that don't have multiple values in A1 so the command can execute. So in the example above, I'd like to remove the row with a value of 3 in column A1 since there is only one entry. Any assistance on how to do this?

Comment: @beginnerR the command is taking too much time to execute. If I just do this for 100 of the rows it takes 2 minutes and I have 3 million rows. Any thoughts to execute quicker?

Comment: @user3922483, who you talking to? Please specify what exactly your desired output, because it seems unclear to most of us

Comment: you have solved my problem with your code above as it is returning the desired output when I try it with a small sample size of my data. The problem I'm having is when I try to run it for my whole data set (3 million rows) it takes too long to execute and never finishes(I let it run for days and it still didn't complete. If I execute this on just 1000 rows it takes 20 minutes. Is there any way I can speed up the operation or be more efficient? It would take over 20 days to do 3 million rows at the current pace